# difference between: number = number + 10; and number += 10;

Tags: c

Is there any difference between these two formats regarding the order of saving the result in the memory?

```
number = number + 10;
number += 10;
```

I recall that one format saves the result immediately so the next line of code can use the new value and regarding the other format the new value can't be used by the next line of code. Am I right or wrong about that?

Comment: One of the two is less typing and has less chance of a typo error. Tha's all.

Answer (score 3):

For almost all practical purposes, there is no difference, at least in the simple case you're asking about.

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to the N1570 draft), section 6.5.15.2, says:

> A compound assignment of the form **`E1`** *op* **`=`** **`E2`** is equivalent to the
>   simple assignment expression **`E1 = E1`** *op* **`(E2)`**, except that the lvalue
>   **`E1`** is evaluated only once, and with respect to an
>   indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound
>   assignment is a single evaluation. If **`E1`** has an atomic type, compound
>   assignment is a read-modify-write operation with **`memory_order_seq_cst`**
>   memory order semantics.

(The text formatting of the above paragraph is a bit tricky; **`+=`** is a single token that can't have a space in the middle of it.)

You can safely ignore most of that. I don't completely understand the last sentence myself.

The relevant difference is that the `number` is evaluated *twice* if you write

```
 number = number + 10;
```

and only once if you write

```
 number += 10;
```

(It's evaluated once for each time it appears in the expression.)

Now if the expression is just the name of a variable, there is no difference. In both cases, the same value is stored in `number`, and the result of the entire expression (which is discarded, but it *could* be used as part of a larger expression) is the new value that was just assigned.

If `number` is declared *volatile*, then the number of times it's evaluated can affect your program's behavior. The details depend on where `number` is stored and the characteristics of your system. Loosely speaking, `volatile` inhibits optimizations, requiring the compiler to generate code that does exactly what you told it to. If the variable is some kind of special register connected with some physical device, it can make a big difference.

If rather than just `number` you have a more complicated expression, evaluating it once vs. twice can also make a big difference. For example:

```
int arr[100] = ...;
arr[rand() % 100] += 10;
arr[rand() % 100] = arr[rand() % 100] + 10;
```

The first assignment increases the value of some random element of `arr`. The second grabs the value of some random element of `arr`, adds 10 to it, and stores the result in some *other* random element of `arr` (or maybe the same one), because `rand()` returns a (probably) different result each time it's called.

But in the simple case you're asking about:

```
number += 10;
```

vs.

```
number = number + 10;
```

both statements do the same thing, and a compiler will *probably* generate exactly the same code for both.

The main purpose of the compound assignment operators like `+=` is to let you write shorter and clearer code (the two don't always go together, but in this case they do). Because you're only operating on a single variable, it makes sense to be able to refer to its name only once. And for more complicated expressions, being able to write:

```
a[b].c[d+42]->e += 10;
```

rather than

```
a[b].c[d+42]->e = a[b].c[d-42]->e;
```

not having to type the name of the target more than once reduces the risk that at typo will introduce a bug. (Did you notice the typo in the second version?)